# ASP.NET Core - Using IServiceProvider within controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I was reading on [Constructor injection behavior (ms docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#constructor-injection-behavior)

I currently have a Transient `EmailSenderService` that is registered in the DI container.

I have a controller that invokes several business-layer services. One of those business services is dependent on the `EmailSenderService`, where an email is sent after several business operations are successful.

- `ControllerA` - Controller that calls business services
- `BusinessServiceA` - Has a dependency of `EmailSenderService`
- `EmailSenderService` - Registered in ASP.NET Core DI container

I am trying to figure out the best approach here... should my controller require `IServiceProvider` as a dependency so I can directly instantiate my `BusinessServiceA` (with its `EmailSenderService` dependency) using something like `ActivatorUtilities`?

If not using the `IServiceProvider` in something like `GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider)` (which is technically a service locator pattern), then what are the other options?

#### Recap:

I have an email provider that are not injected to my controllers, but business services that are called by my controllers use that email provider which is registered with the DI container, so instead of specifying my email provider as a dependency in my controller and passing it to data services, would just using the `IServiceProvider` be the correct approach here?

Comment: Why don't you inject the email sender to your business service?

Comment: @Sasan I apologize if I'm missing something here, but the only way to do that is using the IServiceProvider, correct? `CreateInstance(IServiceProvider)`

Comment: Do not use the service locator pattern wherever possible (if the service type is known in the development time). Because it makes the dependencies *implicit*. That means it’s not possible to see the dependencies easily while creating an instance of the service. This is especially important for unit tests where you may want to mock some dependencies of a service. Resolve dependencies in the service constructor if possible. Resolving in a service method makes your application more complicated and error prone.

Comment: @Andy So basically I am overthinking things here... I should just instantiate the EmailProvider and pass it into the BusinessService?

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate *anything*. Let your DI service pipeline do it. All 3 of those service should be injected in your `ConfigureServices` method (using the `AddTransient`, `AddScoped`, or `AddSingleton` methods). Then you simply just add the needed service as a constructor parameter of the service that depends on it.

Comment: @spencer741 No, dependencies can be chained, so the controller would get the business service from its constructor and the business service would get the email sender from its constructor. `IServiceProvider` and `IServiceScopeFactory` are for special scenarios, like getting a scoped service inside a singleton service, or getting a service from another thread.

Comment: Ah. Duh. I think my lack of sleep has caused this dysphoria. Thanks for the help both of you.

Comment: If you want an example of what we are talking about, I would be more than happy to lay one out.

Comment: I made the mistake of referring to my business layer as a Business Service. It is not a service in the context of DI. My business layer is a collection of async procedures that rush the database (calling data access layer).

Comment: You should re-think how you are doing things. You want to stick to the DI pattern. You shouldn't have "Utility" classes (sometimes called "Helper" classes). It's an antiquated pattern. Everything should be injected as a service. Otherwise you end up in the boat you are currently in :)

Comment: I get what you're saying. Every time I try to buy into full fledged DI, I end up reverting and writing a bunch of utility services. For a few simple business processes and calls to a couple of data-layer utilities, I always have had a tough time reasoning why I should instantiate a bunch of objects to do so.

Comment: For more information on the Service Locator pattern and why it's a bad idea, read [this article](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).

Comment: When I first got in to DI, I did the *exact* same thing you are doing. It's a hard habit to break. But once you break that habit, you'll wonder why you didn't sooner. DI pattern is extremely powerful and allows you to think about a system in a totally new way.